Android Studio Emulator Installed Successfully not showing in Running devices
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the studio, restarting the ADB server, force stoping the
qemu-system. This is Mac M1 chip system previously the build was working then I rolled back and I think at sometime it stopped displaying the emulator.

Once I run the emulator it should be visible in running devices
